# Angular-CLI production build not displaying bootstrap styles

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap

I have added ng-bootstrap v4.0 to the Angular-CLI v1.7 getting started application which when run (ng serve) on a local web server in development mode correctly displays HTML elements with bootstrap styling.

However, when I build a production version (ng build --prod),which includes a 144k css bundle, and load the distribution bundles to a web server, although the page functions correctly no bootstrap styling is applied.

As a beginner can you please suggest what I have missed.

Comment: share ur .angular.cli.json

Comment: and how are you importing bootstrap styles?

Comment: check the console for any errors

Comment: angular.cli.json is unchanged from the angular getting started application. Bootstrap is imported via styles.css. There are no errors reported in the console.

Comment: When I use ng build and deploy the larger files to the server the bootstrap styles are displayed.

Comment: Correction. No errors but 1 warning. CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch in style.xxxx.bundle.css.

Comment: Solution. ng build bundles bootstrap.css in a js file which is sent with Content-Type text/plain. 
ng build --prod bundles bootstrap.css in a css file which is should be sent with Content-Type text/css.
My web server was using text/plain which is blocked by the browser.